# Component @ref inside loop results in empty List

Tags: blazor

I'm new to Blazor and this might be something that I'm overlooking, or this is a bug.

The following code returns error at runtime stating that the index is outside bounds of Guias which is a List:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Guias.Count(); i++)
{
    <GuiaOverviewComponent Guia="Guias[i]" @ref="@guiaOverviews[Guias[i].ExternalId]"></GuiaOverviewComponent>
}
```

But the code works fine if I assign the value of Guias[i].ExternalId to a variable instead of referencing it inside the @ref statement:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Guias.Count(); i++)
{
    string str= Guias[i].ExternalId; 
    <GuiaOverviewComponent Guia="Guias[i]" @ref="@guiaOverviews[str]"></GuiaOverviewComponent>
}
```

Notice that there are no problems when I use Guias[i] when I use it in the same line *Guia="Guias[i]"* but as soon as I use it inside @ref I get the errors at runtime.

Comment: Can you give more info about what your Guias and guiaOverviews contain?  I suspect that you don't need to do any indexing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an *out of Bounds* because `i` will be at `Guias.Count` when the Razor builder tries to compile the code - one beyond the index max.  This is razor code (not a C# class).  It gets pre-compiled into a C# class before compilation.  Hunt in the *obj/debug/net5/razor* folder for the xxx.g.cs file for your component/page to see what's actually being created.   You need to set a local variable in each loop.

```cs
@for (int i = 0; i < Guias.Count(); i++)
{
    var g = Guias[i].
    <GuiaOverviewComponent Guia="g" @ref="will fix in a minute"></GuiaOverviewComponent>
}
```

Next `@ref` assigns the component property to itself. I'm going to assume @guiaOverviews is an array of some kind.  However `@guiaOverviews[str]` doesn't exist,  so you get an error.
If you want to capture each `GuiaOverviewComponent` into a list you need to do something [like this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13358#issuecomment-582057368):

```
@code {
    private List<GuiaOverviewComponent> guiaOverviews= new List<GuiaOverviewComponent>();

    private GuiaOverviewComponent guiaRef 
    {
        set => guiaOverviews.Add(value); 
    }
}
```

With so little code I haven't tested this, so no guarantees it'll compile first time.  It should get you going in the right direction.

There are quite a few similar questions to yours on StackOverflow - search for "Blazor @ref".

Comment: The setter solution to store a list of references works perfectly. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known C#, not just blazor, for loop issue. You need to make a copy of your `i` variable.

Your second example is essentially doing this.

You could change your code to this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Guias.Count(); i++)
{
    var iCopy = i;
    <GuiaOverviewComponent Guia="Guias[iCopy]" @ref="@guiaOverviews[Guias[iCopy].ExternalId]"></GuiaOverviewComponent>
}
```

However I would use a foreach loop:

```
@foreach(var guia in Guias)
{    
    <GuiaOverviewComponent Guia="guia" @ref="@guiaOverviews[guia.ExternalId]"></GuiaOverviewComponent>
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the foreach will likely be the accepted answer.  I find in Blazor I very rarely (like, almost never) have need for indexing.